# Internationalization in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, internationalization

I am working on high charts using internationalization. I have to dynamically change the labels based upon the locale. Does anyone have any examples related to this. It would be really helpful.

Comment: How you recognise which language is used? It should by switched by any button or check i.e browser language and then chart is initialised?

Comment: I can get the locale by switching button. But the problem I am having is how to set the lang options dynamically for highcharts based upon the locale for 5 different languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set the language options. See [`lang`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang). These apply to all charts on a page. You can set your text values to an object/variable (depending on which one you set). Get the localisation of the user (many ways to get this) then set the text values appropriately:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        months: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin',  'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
        weekdays: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi']
    }
});
```

Comment: I was able to set  one language option.  But I  was having trouble with making it dynamic.Can you please explain a little bit further what you mean by setting text values to an object /variable after getting localization.

Comment: @Hary, that would depend on your web technology you are using. We use .NET so in the codebehind we get what language the user is under and we then register the javascript with the appropriate language's text.

Comment: I can get the locale and know what language is user under . But how I set the lang dynamically for 5 different languages based upon the locale?

Comment: I am looking through the highcharts api page but couldn't find the answer, does this mean that highcharts doesn't come bundled with language options for common languages? So for every language we wish to support, we have to provide the full set of localized text for that language ourselves?

Comment: @Bruce, I believe you are correct. You need to roll your own.

Comment: @wergeld Thanks! I guess we have no choice XD

Comment: I use i18next, and I have to connect the two so that the detection is handled by i18next, and the translations pump from my files to highcharts.